# How to block rows in a shared spread sheet in google docs

Tags: google-docs

I am working on a **google spread sheet** that has been **shared** with 10 people.

In that I need to insert some where around 60 new records in that spread sheet (and other people are also inserting new records simultaneously).

Is there any way that I can **lock rows** for example rows starting from 100-160. So that other people cannot insert or update those rows until **I release the lock**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data -> Protected Sheets & Ranges -> Set Range and Permissions

[For more info](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/144687?hl=en)